# Creating heat map weighted by population in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-online, heat-map

I want to create a hotspot map of incidents by City but I would like to weight it by population.

Is this possible in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  What have you tried, and how does (or doesn't) that work for you?  Please provide as much information in your question as possible.  Questions that ask "Is this possible" will very often have an answer of "Yes this is possible".  Please [edit] your question to expand on what you're trying to do, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Are you trying to have this field update on-the-fly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if ArcGIS Online has the ability (yet) to do weighted heat maps. The work around would be to:

1. Add a new field in your attribute table
2. Field calculate to divide the incident field by the population field
3. In symbology, use the new weighted field as the field to symbolize.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the Interpolate Points, Hot Spot Analysis and Density layer under your analysis tools, read the in-line help for each of the tools to determine which one makes sense for your analysis.

I assume you have your 'population' attributed to your incidents layer and can use this as your weighting.  Note you can use the geoenrichment tools to calculate the population for your incidents.  Note you can also apply normalisation using a separate variable (your population variable) without performing a separate field calculation if that is also what you are trying to achieve.  [Weighting](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/search/weight) implies you want to give your incidents more "weight" or influence on the result based on the population, whereas [normalising](http://support.esri.com/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/normalization) by population would be to minimise differences in values based on the population.

Here I have some mock data for incidents within a city with a performance variable tied to them.

[image]

From the analysis tools, I can create a density map and feed in the performance variable as the **weighting**.  This could be your population variable.  You can optionally specify search distance and number of classes to break density result into and classification method and also clip it to an area of interest.

[image]

This creates a new layer.  You can then change the symbology classification, filter the results, etc.

[image]

In this case, the city center banks are not only in closer proximity to neighbouring banks, but they also make more profit (my weighted variable) therefore the density map favours these banks.

You can specify more classes and smaller search distances depending on your requirements.